# using a variable name to load movie clip to stage using As3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, class

I have created a Spelling Puzzle in `AS3` that loads a list of words from an `XML` file into an `Array`.

As the code loops through the array, it assigns each word to a variable called "current_word", then scrambles the letters of "current_word" and displays them on stage.

I would like to add an animated `MovieClip` as a visual aid with the class name that matches the value of current word.

For example if the current word is 'bear', then a `MovieClip` with the class name 'bear' is loaded from library to stage.

I was trying to create an empty movie clip called "tempItemClip" and overwrite its value with the value of the `var current_word`.

No errors, but it's not working. I am new to ActionScript. Can someone advise me on the best solution?

```
  public function getWord() 
  {

     current_word=pWord[ques_num];
     setTiles(current_word.length);
     ques_num++;
     trace(current_word);


     var tempItemClip:MovieClip = new MyItem();
     Puzzle_screen.addChildAt(tempItemClip,4);
     tempItemClip.x=380;
     tempItemClip.y=130;

     //var myClip:Object = getDefinitionByName(current_word);

     var myClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
     tempItemClip[current_word] = myClip;
     tempItemClip.addChild(myClip);

  }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, are you asking how to create an instance of a symbol from the library using as string value ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are asking, but I believe this is what you want :

```
var clipClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(current_word) as Class;
var myClip:MovieClip = new clipClass();
```